# Toggling true/false: editing a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I have some code that tries to change 'false' to 'true' in a ruby file, but it only works once while the script is running.

```
    toggleto = true
    text = File.read(filename)
text.gsub!("#{!toggleto}", "#{toggleto}")
File.open(filename, 'w+') {|file| file.write(text); file.close}
```

As far as I know, as long as I close a file, i should be able to read it it afterwards with what I previously wrote and thus change it back and forth no matter how many times.

Larger Context:

```
def toggleAutoAction

  require "#{@require_path}/options"

  filename = "#{@require_path}/options.rb"

  writeToggle(filename, !OPTIONS[:auto])

  0

end


  def writeToggle(filename, toggleto)

text = File.read(filename)
text.gsub!(":auto => #{!toggleto}", ":auto => #{toggleto}")
File.open(filename, 'w+') {|file| file.write(text); file.close}

  end


  def exitOrMenu

    puts "Are you done? (y/n)"
    prompt

    if gets.chomp == 'n'
      whichAction
    else
      exit
    end

  end


  def whichAction
    if action == 5
  toggleAutoAction
    else
      puts "Sorry, that isn't an option...returning"
  return 1
    end

    exitOrMenu

  end
```

Comment: isn't the file closed automatically after the block, making your call redundant?

Comment: ok good point, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: the issue is I have the program which gives options of actions, one action is to toggle a certain value which is stored in a file (between true and false).  after an action is done the program asks if you are done and if not then it asks you for another action.  if you then use the toggle action again, it won't recognize the change. only after the program ends is the change in the file made, which means that it can only be toggled once in the program. (or so it seems to me)

Comment: Off topic: Shouldn't you store your settings in a designated configuration format, like YAML, JSON or XML? A Ruby script file would not have been my first choice after reading your provided code...

Comment: that's true, but now i'm just curious why my code doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays within this method:

```rb
def toggleAutoAction
  require "#{@require_path}/options"         # here
  filename = "#{@require_path}/options.rb"
  writeToggle(filename, !OPTIONS[:auto])
  0
end
```

Ruby will not load the `options.rb` a second time (i.e. with the exact same path name), hence your `!OPTIONS[:auto]` will only be evaluated once (otherwise you would get a constant-already-defined-warning, provided `OPTIONS` is defined in `options.rb`). See [`Kernel#require`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) docs.

You could, of course, do crazy stuff like

```rb
eval File.read("#{@require_path}/options.rb")
```

but I would not recommend that (performance wise).

As noted [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596809/toggling-true-false-editing-a-file-in-ruby#comment23857296_16596809), reading/writing from/to YAML files is less painful ;-)

Comment: I believe that you __could__ do `load("#{@require_path}/options.rb")` instead of `eval`, but like @DMKE said, it's probably best not to.